# Android - Tabs with zone in common

Tags: android, tabs

first, sorry for my english.

I need to do a actionbar with tabs, and one zone in common.

Like a bottonbar.

That is a picture to example.

http://es.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=nmf85c&s=8#.U5PHD65fJhE

When I move the tabs, the green area does not move

My code is:

```
package com.deimon.wine;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.deimon.wine.TabMomento;/*the code to create the tab, like PlaceholderFragment*/
import com.deimon.wine.TabComida;
import com.deimon.wine.TabPrecio;
import com.deimon.wine.Configuracion;

public class AplicacionActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a {@link FragmentPagerAdapter}
     * derivative, which will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this
     * becomes too memory intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_aplicacion);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });
        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new TabMomento();/*charge the first tab*/
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new TabComida();/*charge the second tab*/
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new TabPrecio();/*charge the thirst tab*/
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.tab1);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.tab2);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.tab3);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: Have you tried to remove this common area and "export" to a new `Fragment`? And include this new `Fragment` in the layout below the `ViewPager`?

Comment: That's pretty straight implementation of view pager and fragments. Have you tried to change your layout a bit? First first half of layout will be a view pager with tabs(Using view pager and fragments) second half of the layout will be just a normal view. Set your view pager height to achieve you are truing to do. Let me know if you need the code for that.

Comment: thank wakim, i have that area in a diferent fragment, but i dont know how insert below in the tabs...


thank you mike, please i need the code

Comment: @deimon I am posting the xml for now.. it should work.. If you want the actual implementation, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question and the requirement, the only thing I did was:

**1)** Set the height of the View Pager

**2)** Add other views below the View Pager and set the height and width as wrap_content and match_parent for width.

Here's the layout for it:

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp" 
        android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/mylistview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="#fff" >
    </View>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text = "fIXED cONTENT"
        android:textSize = "30sp"
        android:textColor = "#fff">        
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how the view looks like now:

[Image http://imageshack.com/a/img834/9374/w36p.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img834/9374/w36p.png)
  [Image http://imageshack.com/a/img843/9553/5n8y.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img843/9553/5n8y.png)

Let me know if you need the implementation of it.

Good Luck..:)

Comment: Thank mike, work perfectly, now only i need a change in the height fixed, but that is easy (maybe). Regards.

Comment: Hey..M glad it helped..Yeah, you can just give your own height to your choice.. It's just one small edit in the xml..:D

Comment: yes but i want the height automatic, dont worry, i should do that. jeje, thank again